# Is there a way to view NATS messages?

Tags: nats.io

I am trying to look at the messages in a NATS cluster on a certain topic.
My google searches led to https://github.com/KualiCo/nats-streaming-console and https://hub.docker.com/r/fjudith/nats-streaming-console but neither npm install nor yarn install worked. I am not sure if thats an issue with the image or if thats my system setting.

And since I am new here, I wasn't allowed to comment.
I have been running in circles for sometime with this so any pointers would be highly appreciated.

-Suresh

Answer (score 3):

Maybe this is not what you are looking for on a cluster (but could be).

Nevermind, in case of a single NATS instance, using the CLI-tools:

**Start with a PING**

```
nats --server Host:Port rtt
```

**General access:**

```
nats --user username --password mypassword --server Host:Port
```

**Listing the streams:**

```
nats --user username --password mypassword --server Host:Port stream ls
```

**Subscribing (a shell) onto a streams:**

```
nats --user username --password mypassword --server Host:Port subscribe SUBJECT.STREAM
```

**Publish a "JSON message" onto a stream:**

```
cat <PathToMessage.json> | nats --user username --password mypassword --server Host:Port publish SUBJECT.STREAM --force-stdin
```

**Show all messages published onto a Stream:**

```
nats --user username --password mypassword --server Host:Port stream view
```

**Additionally: Sample JSON Message:**

```
{
  "id": "4152c2e7-f2be-42d8-86fe-5b94f2ed3678",
  "form": "triangle",
  "wrappedData": {
    "Color": "green",
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the nats CLI tool (https://github.com/nats-io/natscli/releases/):

To look at the messages being published on subject `foo` for example just use `nats sub foo`.

Note that NATS-Streaming (aka STAN) is now deprecated and replaced by JetStream which is built-in to the nats.io server.

Answer (score 0):

You can use WEB UI (not good as in rabbit, but..) It's forked version of nats-webui. I am not maintainer, but it works. Also it can work with auth tokens.

Github: https://github.com/suisrc/NATS-WebUI

DockerHub: https://hub.docker.com/r/suisrc/nats-webui/tags

Comment: Also you can use https://github.com/devfacet/natsboard but there is no any variants to see messages :c